# Make pg_search return results for prefixes AND postfixes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg-search

I am using the pg_search gem in Rails 4.2 to search names in a model.  I have the following:

```
pg_search_scope :search_for_dashboard,
    lambda { |q|
      {
        against: [:name, :email, :description],
        using: {
          tsearch: {
            prefix: true
          }
        },
        ignoring: :accents,
        query: q
      }
    }
```

If I type `ad` or `Ad`, I get results with 'Adnan' and 'Adrian'.  What I want is that if I type `an` I also get the same results.  Or if I type `dnan` I get 'Adnan'.  Is that possible with pg_search?

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of pg_search.

One way you could get postfix searching to work would be to use trigram search instead of tsearch. Trigram searches work against any part of the string.

Alternatively, it would be possible to add a `postfix` option for tsearch that works similarly to `prefix`, but that would require adding new functionality to the gem.

Comment: Does multisearchable add trigram search? @nertzy